# Make In App Browser ask for geolocation permission

Tags: javascript, inappbrowser, messenger, viber

When I open my link in a Chrome or Firefox it shows a popup message like this

> This site wants to know your location (Allow)(Block)

It works well when I open it in an external browser. However the problem is when I open the page thru In App Browser of Messenger and Viber mobile app. The popup message doesn't show anymore and it is not getting the location of my device.

I tried to hack my way in by calling the geolocation.getCurrentPosition twice, but no luck.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, to access the location from WebView you need to add permissions for the same

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

But in your case, you are using a third party app and browser so you can manage permission from them that's why you can access GeoLocation from external Browser but not within the in-App Browser.

Maybe providing manually permission from settings to apps may help. I'm not sure but you can try.